# How to force default timezone for as.Date

Tags: r, oracle, datetime, timezone

How to force R to have default timezone `"Europe/Paris"` on `as.Date` functions?

I tried:

`Sys.setenv(tz='Europe/Paris')` at the top of the script file - doesn't work

Would like to avoid adding a suffix `tz="Europe/Paris"` to every single `as.Date` call

EXAMPLE:

I have a function that pulls data from SQL database:

```
historyDateStart=toupper(format(as.POSIXlt(strptime(historyDateStart, "%d-%b-%y")),"%d-%b-%y"))

query=paste("SELECT price
FROM price_history
              WHERE date_field BETWEEN TO_DATE('",
              historyDateStart,
              "', 'dd-MON-yy') AND TO_DATE('",
              historyDateEnd,
              "', 'dd-MON-yy')
              ORDER BY date_field ",sep="")


  data=getoracledata(query,databaseName)
```

If I don't add `tz="Europe/Paris"` to as.Date functions then I'm getting data with time 23:00:00 & day before. That's even if I run the env.put before running this.

Comment: Who told you it didn't work? What `Sys.timezone()` or `Sys.time()` gives you?

Comment: `"Date"` class objects don't have a time zone.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck but `as.Date()` does, understandably,  take a `tz=` argument

Comment: Only `as.Date.POSIXct` but not in general.

Comment: @DavidArenburg nobody told me, I tried it and all as.Date statements default to the windows timezone.

Comment: How can you tell? Can you show an example?

Comment: Hi David please see the edit